# Different font width in @string of TextView

Tags: android, textview, typography, android-fonts, android-typeface

I have the string `<string name="getStarted">Get Started!</string>`.

I have set it's textview to `android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"`.

Can I have the `Started!` as a regular fontFamily where the rest of the string (`Get`) having a light weight?

I tried: 
`<string name="getStarted">Get <n>Started!</n></string>` like `<b></b>` but well... `n` is not a tag (n for normal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For consistency, based on @Gavin2058 's answer.

```
SpannableString sb = new SpannableString("Get Started!");
sb.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan("sans-serif"), 4, 11, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
yourTextView.setText(sb);
```

`SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE` helps you add more `setSpan` of the same style if you have a big string with multiple width words.

Answer (score 1):

```
final SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("Get Started!");  
final StyleSpan bss = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD); // Span to make text bold  
sb.setSpan(bss, 4, 11, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE); // make them also bold 
yourTextView.setText(sb);
```

Comment: So I have to convert all the `android:Text` and make them programmatically, huh? Pity there is not an easier way. Also that's a bit messed up for multilingual apps. :/